# A mysterious react hook problem occuring randomly

Tags: reactjs, react-select, visual-studio-2022

I have been trying to get react-select to work but somehow i have failed in every turn. What ever i have tried is:

1-create react project using vs2022 
2-install react-select using "PM > npm i --save react-select" command
3-modify home.js as in following

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select'

export class Home extends Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Select />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

4-Hit F5 key.

The above attempt results in  Invalid hook call error. I have no idea what i have been doing wrong.

Comment: How did you call `Home` component in `App.js`?

Comment: <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />. I have made no other changes to the vs-generated react project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized that aforementioned problem is not something specific to react-select. It exists in every single component that I have tried so far...

Problem is; I was using Package Manager Console ( PM ) which installs components under [PROJECT_DIR]/node_modules directory.

Navigating to [PROJECT_DIR]/clientapp  using *cd clientapp* in **Developer Powershell** (PS) and then issuing same npm command fixes the problem.